# Everybody works together on the floor

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found this expression in a US book, it refers to kitchen work. Does it mean that people work very close to each other? Or something else?

Comment: "On the floor", in a workplace (such as a retail store or a commercial kitchen) refers to the place where most workers do their work -- the "sales floor" for a retail store and the actual kitchen area for a commercial kitchen.  Ie, not in the back offices.  The term would not generally be used to refer to a household kitchen, except then referring to the actual floor where that egg landed and splattered all over everything.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are all one team, and you should feel free to cooperate with each other.